# What is postgres uuid_generate_v4() maximum?

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I have logs table with many rows where pk is generated by `uuid_generate_v4()` function.

What i'm curious about - is there a limit for generated uuids? Like if i will have 10.000.000.000 rows it will not able to generate unique primary key.

Comment: UUIDs are 128-bit numbers, the space is huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a UUID is a 128 bit number, the maximum of different UUIDs would be 2^128 = 340.282.366.920.938.463.463.374.607.431.768.211.456 (if that big number calculator made no mistake but it sure is very, very large). So you're far, far, far away from that with just 10.000.000.000.

Comment: But you would get collisions before that, right?